# .css display animation issues

Tags: jquery, css

Hi I'd have put together basic jquery to make a menu at the top of a page appear, can I make this slide in from the top rather than just appear suddenly. I've tried to use .animate but couldn't place it correctly

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#toggle').click(function(){
    $('div.menu').css('display', 'block');
  });
});
```

Comment: How about `$('div.menu').slideToggle()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use slide functions from jQuery library. `slideDown` to open, `slideUp` to hide.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#toggle').click(function(){
    $('div.menu').slideDown('slow');
  });
});
```